# Kubuntu 15.04 failure to dual boot, missing GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, uefi, 15.04

I've been dual booting Kubuntu and Windows 8.1 for some time now and just today I upgraded to 15.04 and it's been nothing but problems. Mainly, I can no longer boot into Kubuntu; I don't even get the GRUB menu anymore.

I've tried all I know to do (changing UEFI settings, etc.) and still nothing. Honestly, I'm about ready to frag my Windows partitions, unfortunately I can't do that until I get Kubuntu up and running again. Simply, I want to know what the heck I gotta do to get this working again, w/o uninstalling 15.04 and reinstalling 14.04.

Comment: Which UEFI settings did you change? Same result with all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Some shot-in-the-dark suggestions, in no particular order:

- [Disable Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) in your firmware setup utility.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and boot from it. If you can get it, you can attempt subsequent repairs from your full installation.
- Use an emergency boot system to install [any EFI boot loader of your choice.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) Many of these are easier to set up and repair manually than GRUB. (rEFInd is one of these options.)
- Run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on your system. If this step doesn't work, save the URL it presents and, if you can't get your system booting, post the URL here.

If you need more help, be sure to post your Boot Repair output. Without it (or equivalent data gathered manually), we're left guessing at the cause of your problem.